# git filter-branch is not removing my appsettings.json from GitHub

Tags: git, github

When i originally created this project I didnt know its not best practice to commit the appsettings.json file to a repo. So when i pushed my project to GitHub it contained the appsettings.json. Now much later in development I realized from reading some articles about security that having the appsettings.json with my connection string in there is a slight security risk even if the repo is private. I found GitHub has a page where they tell u to run the command

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch appsettings.json" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

When I run this it seems to run through everything but at the end I just get that everything was unchanged, remote/master, head/master, and all my tags so i dont know whats going on, why the command isnt working. This is my first time trying this so maybe i am missing something small. Any help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: Was the appsettings.json inside a file named `dir`?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger 'dir' is the stand in for the name of my solution as it said i needed to put the path to the file within the project file, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up seeing that what I needed was a proper backslash '/' before my file name and i also removed all the pruning and tag commands at the end. This made all the changes to my repo and removed the appsettings file from the history of my github repo then i just pushed the changes to the origin and my repo was clean of any security risk.

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ProjectName/appsettings.json"
```